# Display a tab on activating a menu item

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtabbedpane, jmenuitem

How can we display a `JTabbedPane` through clicking a menu item within a menu bar?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into `setSelectedIndex()` and `setSelectedComponent()` in the javadocs. You can usually find methods similar to these in the docs.

[`JTabbedPane#setSelectedComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedComponent%28java.awt.Component%29)